# Observable.interval() + flatMap() weird behavior

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, observable

I am trying to chain `Observable.interval()` with `.flatMap()` but I am getting (*what i think is*) an unexpected behavior.

This is the code I am using (with Angular 2):

```
Observable.interval(1500)
  .scan( (numArr:any[],curr:any,i:number) => {
    numArr.push(i);
    return numArr;
  }, [])
  .do(arr => console.log('interval value', arr))
  .flatMap(numArr => {
    return Observable.interval(500)
      .map(i => {
        numArr.forEach((el, i, arr) => {
          arr[i] += 1;
        })
        return numArr;
      })
  }).subscribe(res => console.log('final value', res));
```

and the result I am getting is

```
interval value [0]
final value [1]
final value [2]
interval value [2, 1]
final value [3, 2]
final value [4, 3]
final value [5, 4]
final value [6, 5]
final value [7, 6]
interval value [7, 6, 2]
final value [8, 7, 3]
final value [9, 8, 4]
final value [10, 9, 5]
....
```

**I would expect to receive 3 values between each "interval value"** cycle instead i get a bigger list each time the interval emits a value... Why is this happening and how could I avoid that behavior?

What I would like to achieve is to increment by *1* each value of the array emitted by the first `Observable.interval()` each 500ms.
In other words what I would expect is:

```
interval value [0]
final value [1]
final value [2]
final value [3]
interval value [3, 1]
final value [4, 2]
final value [5, 3]
final value [6, 4]
interval value [6, 4, 1]
final value [7, 5, 2]
final value [8, 6, 3]
final value [9, 7, 4]
....
```

Hope you can help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. I don't know whether I'm fully understanding what you are going for here (also there's quite a lot going on as you are mutating the original array in the flatMap) but nevertheless this is where I would go from here:

The observable you create inside flatMap does not terminate - it keeps on incrementing the values in numArr even when another interval value has already come in. This means after 2 interval values have come in you actually increment all values in numArr twice each 500 ms, after 3 interval values thrice, and so on.
What you want (increment all values thrice, then add another value to the array, in this case each 500ms, and repeat) can be achieved by limiting the Observable in flatMap to three loops with .take(3).

You would get the same desired behavior by using concatMap rather than flatMap as it concats (one observable runs at the time, the next only starts when the previous has finished) the observables created inside rather than merging them (all Observables run at the same time). Not that you should do that :D, go with the take(3).

Answer (score 0):

The second `flatMap()` should be converted into a `switchMap()`, so the interval observables will not be left pending.